# Batch files running as an admin won't create a text file

Tags: batch-file

Running the following batch file will create a text file only if I am **not** running it as an administrator. Why?

```
@echo off
(echo This is a test) > test.txt
```

Comment: Yes. When I start it as admin it won't create the file. However, If I start it **not** as admin, it **will** create the file.

Comment: Excuse me, pay attention that when you start dos prompt as admin you are working on system32 folder. This can represent some matter. Try cd.. cd.. and echo again. In my local test works as admin and not as admin.

Comment: Best guess: you have antivirus software which forbids even an admin from writing to system32

Comment: Sorry I should clarify what I was doing. If I start up dos prompt as admin, and then run the .bat file, it will create the .txt correctly. However, what I was trying to do was right-click the .bat and run as administrator. **That** doesn't work.

Comment: Which folder is this .bat file?

Comment: The file is in my C: folder

Comment: Just figured it out. For some reason the file is getting deposited into my System32 folder. Best guess is the file is being created there because that's essentially admin's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File was getting deposited to system32 - most likely because that's admin's default directory.

Comment: Yeah, there are oddities like that. Another bizarre one like it is that double-clicking a batch file (or, any program really) makes it run in the folder it's located in, but dragging and dropping another file onto it, to feed it as command line parameter to the one you're running, will mysteriously make it run from the user's default folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

And what happens if you try it like that :

```
@echo off
(echo This is a test) > "%~dp0test.txt"
```

Comment: No idea. Consider it compensated with my upvote. I love using that little "running file's own directory" construct, and unlike OP's own answer, this actually _solves_ the problem.